# Conjugation with こと and もの

Tags: conjugations, particle-こと

In my textbook, I did an exercise with the following sentences, where you must conjugate the verb in parentheses and put it on the underline (below is the translation I think matches the original sentence):

> 1. せっかく手に入れた宝物を、そんなに簡単に他人に_____ものか。(渡す)
>
> How could I pass to someone else this treasure I've had so much trouble to get?
>
> 2. ジョッギングを始めてみたが、果たしていつまで_____ことだろう。(続く)
>
> I just started jogging, but how long can I continue?
>
> 3. かおりさんはもう書類は全部_____とのことだ。(提出する)
>
> Seems like Kaori has already handed in all the documents. (Not sure how to translate that とのことだ but I know what it means)

For (1), I put `渡せる`, but the answer was `渡す`.
For (2), I put `続ける` but the answer was `続く`
Finally, for (3) I put `提出している` but it was `提出した`.

I understand why the expected answers are correct, but were mine correct too?

*I apologize to pack three questions that are not really related to each other, but I don't think it's necessary to post three times for that*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right.

1. かおりさんはもう書類は全部提出しているとのことだ。
2. かおりさんはもう書類は全部提出したとのことだ。
3. かおりさんはもう書類は全部提出していたとのことだ

Both mean かおり has done that.
Now, とのことだ often translated as 'one heard that ...' or use らしい instead. It doesn't matter to the person heard this news from かおり or via the third party person.

Case 1, Someone told me that かおり has already handed ...  (not confirmed/accepted by the receiver)
Case 2a, かおり told me that she has already handed ...  (not confirmed by the receiver)
Case 2b, The receiver told me that かおり has already handed ... (confirmed)
Case 3, かおり had already handed ... (This needs another person or tense in competition)

All together, you answer should be correct, too. The question should have other contents to fill in the blank.